# hibernate optional join - need to return join column value either way

Tags: hibernate

as a follow on from [hibernate optional join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231579/hibernate-optional-join)

Many existing queries in the system rely on there being a mapped relationship between EntityOne and EntityTwo and changing this is not an attactive option, however I now need to start storing and retrieving values in `tbl_one.two_id` which do not exist in the joined table. On the way in, this works fine with the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_one")
public class EntityOne
{
    ....
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "two_id")
    private EntityTwo two;
    ....
}
```

.. However when querying, if a result has a value for `two_id` which does not exist in the joined table, the value for the field `two` is null and I have no way of telling what the value for `tbl_one.two_id` actually is. I was hoping hibernate would create a dummy `EntityTwo` object and populate it's id field only if the relationship did not exist.

I've also tried mapping `two_id` to another field without a join:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_one")
public class EntityOne
{
    ....
    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "two_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private EntityTwo two;

    @Column(name = "two_id")
    private String twoId;
    ....
}
```

... but then the `two` field is never populated, even when the corresponding record exists.

Essentially I need some way of inserting/updating a value for `tbl_one.two_id` and retrieving a joined entity for `EntityTwo` if the relationship exists, or just the value for `tbl_one.two_id` if the relationship does not exist.

I'm hoping to be able to solve this without creating two mappings for the same table.

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work :

```
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "two_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private EntityTwo two;

@Formula("two_id")
private String twoId;
```

Hibernate will select the two_id column twice : once to populate the two relationship, and once to populate the twoId. The twoId property is read-only, though.

You could also do the reverse, but then it's the two property which will become read-only:

```
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinFormula("two_id")
private EntityTwo two;

@Column("two_id")
private String twoId;
```

Comment: with your JoinFormula eg i'm getting `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column this_.two_two_id does not exist` when querying ... ? i'm guessing that the `value` "two_id" should be something else but i can't find examples online .. can you help?

Comment: there really is no documentation for JoinFormula :(

Comment: The documentation is very light indeed. Try with @JoinFormula(value="two_id", referencedColumnName="two_id") and look at the generated SQL to see what to put as attribute values. Also, look at http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5041 and http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5171 for indices on how it could work.

Comment: yeah still makes no sense to me. i tried with `value="x",referencedColumnName="y"` and the error message was still `column this_.two_two_id does not exist` so i have no idea.

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using. JoinFormula is usable stand-alone since 3.6.0.Beta1. I you use a previous version, try with @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
{ @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="two_id")) })

Comment: i was trying with 3.5 so that might be part of the problem :( unfortunately i had to go with 2 mappings for the one table - one for querying and the other for CRUD. i'll give you the tick because you're most probably right, but using a beta release is not an option for this project either. thanks for the help. p.

Comment: @pstanton: The latest stable release is 3.6.1 Final. This is not a beta release.